# Output only values that do not contain HTML tags in parentheses from PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, regex

Here is a sample PHP array that explains my question well

```
$array = array('1' => 'Cookie Monster (<i>eats cookies</i>)',
               '2' => 'Tiger (eats meat)',
               '3' => 'Muzzy (eats <u>clocks</u>)',
               '4' => 'Cow (eats grass)');
```

All I need is to return only values that don't contain any tag enclosed with parentheses from this array:

```
- Tiger (eats meat)
- Cow (eats grass)
```

For this I'm going to use the following code:

```
$array_no_tags = preg_grep("/[A-Za-z]\s\(^((?!<(.*?)(\h*).*?>(.*?)<\/\1>).)*$\)/", $array);
foreach ($array_no_tags as $a_n_t) {echo "- ".$a_n_t."<br />";}
```

Assuming that `[A-Za-z]` may be **whoever**, `\s` is a **space**, `\(` is the **opening parenthesis**, `^((?!` is **start** of the tag denial statement, `<(.*?)(\h*).*?>(.*?)<\/\1>` is the **tag** itself, `).)*$` is **end** of the tag denial statement and `\)` is the **closing parenthesis**.

Nothing works.

`print_r($array_no_tags);` returns empty array.

Comment: I think strip_tags will work for you. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: how about using a lookahead: [`/^(?!.*?\([^)<]*<\w)/`](https://eval.in/736477)

Comment: @bobble bubble, your reply is quite a working one, could you repost it as answer so I could upvote it?

Comment: Glad it's also helpful (: I put answer too (upvoted Josh's answer already which I think is very accurate).

Comment: Actually Josh's one doesn't suit another case I've faced right today, at the same time yours example matched it perfectly. And vice versa. While both cases look similarly for me, there is a hidden difference I still haven't recognized. So you've also saved a lot of time and efforts to me, **thanks**!

Comment: One difference is, that Josh's regex does require a closing tag so it won't treat singleton tags like `<img...>`. That is not clear from question as your regex let's assume this is desired behaviour. My pattern is rather loose and basic it just looks for not any `<[wordchar]` inside parenthesis so actually it would fail on something like `<1` because word-characters contain digits too. To make it a bit more accurate replace `<\w` with `<[a-z]` to require a letter at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following expression to match strings with HTML tags inside of parentheses:

```
/\([^)]*<(\w+)>[^<>]*<\/\\1>[^)]*\)/
```

Then set the [`PREG_GREP_INVERT` flag](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) to `true` in order to only return items that don't match.

```
$array_no_tags = preg_grep("/\([^)]*<(\w+)>[^<>]*<\/\\1>[^)]*\)/", $array, true);
```

**Explanation:**

- `\(` - Match the literal `(` character

  - `[^)]*` - Negated character class to match zero or more non-`)` characters
  - `<(\w+)>` - Capturing group one that matches the opening element's tag name
  - `[^<>]*` - Negated character class to match zero or more non-`<>` characters
  - `<\/\1>` - Back reference to capturing group one to match the closing tag
  - `[^)]*` - Negated character class to match zero or more non-`)` characters
- `\)` - Match the literal `)` character

---

If you don't care about the parentheses around the element tag, then you could also just use the following simplified expression:

```
/<(\w+)>[^<>]+<\/\\1>/
```

And likewise, you would use:

```
$array_no_tags = preg_grep("/<(\w+)>[^<>]+<\/\\1>/", $array, true);
```

Comment: Actually your previous answer was also a working one. What is the difference? (I'll keep it in this answer, just in case) `$array_no_tags = preg_grep("/<(\w+)>[^<>]+<\/\\1>/", $array, true);`

Comment: @user3354912 - Yeah, that one worked, but when I re-read the question I realized that I wasn't checking for the parentheses, so I updated it.

Comment: One more additional **big thank you** for the explanation. It's quite enough to start regexping myself gradually. :)

Comment: @user3354912 - If you're just starting off with regular expressions, I would highly suggest checking out regex101.com, here is [the example](https://regex101.com/r/oxkLqE/1) I used when I was testing my answer. It's extremely helpful since it gives you feedback while you're typing. That's basically how I learned.

Comment: It is actually the first time I have faced necessity of using regexps. They look scary but in fact they are not so, especially when there is someone who bothers himself with explanations )

Answer (score 1):

You pattern looks a bit overcomplicated. I thought maybe a simple pattern inside the negative lookahead that checks for not any `<x` inside `(` `)` could be sufficient.

```
$array_no_tags = preg_grep("/^(?!.*?\([^)<]*<\w)/", $array);
```

[PHP demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/737052)

So this does [not match `(?!` if](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) there is an `(` opening bracket, followed by `[^)<]*` any amount of [characters that are not](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `)` or `<`, followed by `<\w` lesser sign that's followed by a [word character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html).

Bear in mind that there are nice [regex tools like regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/iCVfbJ/1) available for testing patterns.

Comment: > You pattern looks a bit overcomplicated

...That's what happens when one tries to compile an expression from different sources, while he barely understands what he sees on the screen )

Comment: @user3354912 I remember how confusing all that was for me too when I started using regex almost 15 years ago, but I soon liked it. I put the [link to regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/iCVfbJ/1) with answer. On right top there is an explanation window that explains every detail of the pattern.

Comment: @user3354912 Just to mention: If your elements contain newlines, use with *dotall* [flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for making the dot also match newlines: [`/^(?!.*?\([^)<]*<\w)/s`](https://www.regex101.com/r/wED7Na/1)